# How to fix "Oracle Client library is at version 0.0 but must be at version 11.2 or higher" with nodeJs

Tags: node.js, oracle

I have downloaded the oracledb inside my test project, and when i run my code, it tells me that:

> Oracle Client library is at version 0.0 but must be at version 11.2 or
>   higher

On another hand, I have downloaded the oracle instant client, and set the system path to the file, but it still raises!

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "hr",
    password      : "welcome",
    connectString : "localhost/XEPDB1"
  },
  function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Connection was successful!');

    connection.close(
      function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return;
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Somewhere you have a pre-11.2 version of Oracle installed and Node.js is using that. 

For background about the 0.0 and 11.2, and info about solving your issue, ssee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54697215/confusion-deciphering-error-code-python-module-to-connect-to-oracle-cx-oracle/54700419#54700419 )

Comment: @ChristopherJones
Thank you very much, finally it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause might be that the instant client is too new.

I stumbled upon this with a combination of `node-oracledb` version `4.0.1` and Oracle instant client version `19.3`. Produced exactly the error described.

What worked was to download Oracle instant client version `12.2`.

Comment: It is more likely that 19.3 was installed incorrectly.  Many, many people are using 19.3 without an issue.

Comment: It might be the case but please explain how one is to "install" basic lite instant client? It consists just of unpacking the downloaded archive and setting `PATH` correctly. If `PATH` is not set up correctly, you end up with a very different error message. There are no other Oracle client or server libraries on my machine.